# Compile source and run as cron job

Tags: linux, compilation, cron, server, operating-system

I would like to compile some [C++ code](https://github.com/lvdmaaten/bhtsne/) from source and then run a Python wrapper on my web hosting server as a cron job. I compiled it on my Mac, uploaded onto the server and, unsurprisingly, the server running Linux complained saying:

```
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

I do not have the rights to run `g++ sptree.cpp tsne.cpp -o bh_tsne -O2` on the server. Is there a way for me to obtain a compiled binary that would be compatible with whatever OS (Linux) the server is running on? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially the reason people moved to java, which is platform independent.

For C++, you need the specific link libraries for the target machine.  Some compilers have the option of choosing the linker objects by flag (or setting) and allowing someone to "script" the final executable output. I cant say if the Mac does...